# Regexp for recognizing constructor declarations

Tags: java, regex

I am working on segment of code which needs to be able to recognize no-args constructor declarations in Java source files. While these declarations need to be syntactically correct, they may still be spread across several lines, for example:

```
public MyCons()
```

or

```
public
   MyCons()
```

or even

```
public

   MyCons
  (

    )
```

I am very new to regexp in Java, so I am not sure how to get this working. What I have tried so far is this:

```
public[\\s|\\n]*MyCons[\\s|\\n]*\\(\\S+\\)
```

It does not seem to detect cases involving multiple alternating whitespaces and newlines though, as in the last example above. Also, it would be great if I could replace MyCons with a regular expression accepting just a word (although this is not strictly necessary).

How could I solve this?

Comment: Dont overcomplicate! Doesn't `public\\s+MyCons\\s*\\(\\s*\\)` work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the syntax should be `[\\s\\n]` or `(\\s|\\n)`, not `[\\s|\\n]`, but `\\s` includes `\\n` so try jlordo's suggestion.

Comment: @Dukeling: As you can see in [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), `\s` includes `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use backreference since class name and constructor name is always same..

```
class\\s*([a-zA-Z\\d$]+).*?(public\\s+\\1\\s*\\(\\s*\\))
```

`Group 2` captures the required constructor

You need to use `DOTALL` regex option while matching

Comment: +1, Great general solution. But `\\s*\\1` should be `\\s+\\1` because there has to be a whitespace between the access modifier and the class name ;)

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick, and works real fast too! Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how can I modify this expression to recognize constructor with parameters as well?? I have tried replacing \\(\\s*\\) with \\(\\w+\\), but it does not appear to do the trick.

Comment: @chrsva - Replace `\\(\\s*\\)` with `\\([^)]*\\)`, so the full regex is `class\\s*([a-zA-Z\\d$]+).*?(public\\s+\\1\\s*\\([^)]*\\))`. This will work with or without parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Another short way to recognize the code:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
s.equals("publicMyCons()");
```